# How to display only department name for the department ID using join in python?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

[image]By importing psycopg2 in python with employee database. I'm trying insert new employee details and to display all details about employee except for department ID in employee table it should display department name. I couldn't able to figure out, any idea would be helpful..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MSB7.png)

[image]
This is my PostgreSQL employee and department table

This is my python code:

```
import datetime

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="emp", user="postgres",
                    password="12345", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")

cur = conn.cursor()

emp_name = str(input("Enter new employee name: "))
while True:
    gender = str(input("Type your gender: "))
    if gender == 'M' or gender == 'F':
        break
hire_date = input("Enter hire date(YYYY-MM-DD): ")
year, month, day = map(int, hire_date.split('-'))
hiredate = datetime.date(year, month, day)
deptid = str(int(input("Enter department ID: ")))
salary = str(int(input("Enter your salary: ")))
cur.execute("INSERT INTO employee(emp_name, gender, hire_date, 
             deptid, salary) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", 
            (emp_name, gender, hire_date, deptid, salary))
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM employee")
rows = cur.fetchall()
print('\n'.join(str(row) for row in rows))
print("Created successfully!")

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either select only department_name by passing `deptid` or use `psycopg2.extras`

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT deptname 
      from department where deptid = %(department_id)d''', {'department_id': deptid})
```

Or if you want to join by passing employee id

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT deptname 
      from department d join 
       employee e 
 on d.deptd = e.deptid where empno = %(employee_id)d''',
{'employee_id': empid} ) #empid from user input


import psycopg2.extras
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
cur.execute("""SELECT * from department""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print (" Department name :  ", row['deptname']) #display department name
```

**EDIT**

> But I want to display all the details of employee with deptname
>   instead of deptid

Use a query like this

```
SELECT e.emp_no,e.emp_name,e.gender, --other columns except deptid
       d.deptname
             from department d join 
           employee e 
     on d.deptd = e.deptid where e.empno = ?  pass the required empno
```

Comment: I'm getting error while using `%d` and this is my error showing `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kousic/PycharmProjects/sample/New/New Project.py", line 24, in <module>
    cur.execute('''SELECT deptname FROM department d JOIN employee e on d.deptid = e.deptid where emp_no = %(employee_id)d''', {'employee_id': emp_no})
  File "/home/kousic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 144, in execute
    return super(DictCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) at index 102`

Comment: It's working!  But I want to display all the details of employee with deptname instead of deptid                                                                                                     `Enter new employee name: xyz
Type your gender: M
Enter hire date(YYYY-MM-DD): 2010-10-10
Enter department ID: 5
Enter your salary: 10000
['IT']
Created successfully! `

Comment: @Kousic : Check the edits. Modify your code block  using this join query.

Comment: Actually I'm inserting new employee data to show details with deptname for the user input deptid like in the previous comment

Comment: How to display department id with department name as reverse. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kousic : This answered your original question. If you have another requirement, please post it as a new question.

Comment: @Kousic : Downvoting was not necessary. You could have just explained what's not working. Same goes to the other answer you downvoted